# How to redirect the page based on login success and using single form in multiple condition

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here I have two button one is **login** button and second one is **go to rent.php** .my requirement is if i am clicking login button means i want to show login form in modal,after that user enter their credential and also succfully logged in means i want to redirect the home page(index.php). Now i coming to main point suppose i am clicking **go to rent.php** means ,First  i have to check this user is already logged in or not , suppose logged in means directly i have to redirect the **rent.php**.Suppose he is not yet logged means i have to show the login form in modal after that user will enter the email & password suppose successfully logged in means now i have to redirect the **rent.php** ,How can do this please any one update my answer.

```js
function checkLogin(argument) {
   $('#modalForm').modal('show');
  }
  
  // Login Check
  
   $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#loginbtn").click(function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
                    var loginEmail = $('#loginEmail').val(); 
                    var password = $('#password').val(); 
                   
                      $.ajax({
                       type:'POST',
                       url :"test_session.php",
                       data: {email: loginEmail, password: password},
                       success: function(response) {
                        if(response['status'] =='success'){
                          console.log(response);
                         window.location.href = "index.php"; 
                        }
                      else{
                       
                           $("#update_Failed").show(); 
                        }
                         },
                     error:function(exception){
                     alert('Exeption:'+exception);
                    }
                    });
             }); 
           });
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login Form</h4>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
               <form id="loginForm">
                  <div class="form-group" id="loginmobile">
                      <label for="email">Email address or Mobile:</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control stl" name="email" id="loginEmail" required="" data-msg-required="Please Enter Valid Email or Mobile no." aria-required="true">
                      </div>
                          <div class="form-group" id="loginmobile1"  style="display:none">
                            <label for="email"> Mobile:</label>
                              <input type="number" class="form-control stl" name="email1" id="loginMobile" required="" data-msg-required="Please Enter  Mobile no." aria-required="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" id="otppwd">
                            <!-- <label for="pwd">Password Or OTP:</label> -->
                              <label for="pwd">Password :</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control stl" name="password" id="password" required="" data-msg-required="Please Enter Password" aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                      
                           
                             </br>
                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <button type="submit" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-default contact_us_btn rentListLogin" >SUBMIT</button>
                           
                            </div>
                      
                              <div class="alert alert-danger" id="update_Failed" style="display:none;margin-top: 5%">
                              <br>
                                    <strong>Username or Password is Incorrect</strong> 
                            </div><br>
                      </form> 
            </div>
            
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<a type="button" class="btn" onclick="checkLogin()">Login</a>
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['userName'])){
?>
<a href='rent.php' type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go to rent.php</a>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="checkLogin()">go to rent.php</a>
 <?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check set a variable to identify if the user is logged in or not. Then using that decide whether to show log in modal or go to rent.php page.

```
<script>
<?php 
if(!empty($_SESSION['userName'])){
    var loggedIn = 1;
}
else {
    var loggedIn = 0;
}
?>

function checkLogin(argument) {
    if(loggedIn === 0) {
        $('#modalForm').modal('show');    
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "rent.php";
    }       
}  
 // Login Check        
</script>
```